# CKEditor character count JavaScript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I placed the Jquery and CSS from the below link into my website.

http://jsfiddle.net/VagrantRadio/2Jzpr/

But I can't see the character countdown.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your issue, the code is working as intended.

Comment: The characters do count down, I can clearly see them and the progress par on the top right of the edit panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
jQuery(function() {
    //set up the editor instance for ckeditor
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('textcounter', {
    toolbar: [['Source'], ['Cut', 'Copy', 'PasteText'], ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'], ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'], ['SpecialChar']]
    });
    //global for editor instance
    var global = editor;
    //set timed interval to run function
    setInterval(function updateCount() {
        var almost = $("<div />").html(global.getData()).text();
        var count = 140 - almost.length;
        if(almost.length <= 140) {
            jQuery('#counter').text(count).removeClass("red");
            jQuery('.bar').stop().animate({"width": value+'%'}, 1).removeClass("redbar").addClass("bluebar");
        } else {
            jQuery('#counter').text(count).addClass("red");
            jQuery('.bar').stop().animate({"width": '100%'}, 1).removeClass("bluebar").addClass("redbar");
        }
    }, 500);
});
```